# SQL management studio add-in development in Visual Community (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssms

Can I develop SQL Management Studio Add-In (I need to add some items to context menu) using Visual Studio Community (C#)?

Can not see such type of a project in VS menu.

I found this article:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073839/Create-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-Addin

It says I need Add-in project template, I installed almost all components in VS installer, but still don't have it.

Please, advise, if I can somehow inlcude this template. Or if there are another ways to develop such a thing (add some items to context menu in SQL Management Studio).

Maybe I need to get Visual Studio Enterprise or Professional version.

Thank you!

Comment: Run the *visual studio installer*. Select *visual studio extension development* under *other toolsets* on the *workloads* tab.  When complete you can search for *vsix* in the new solution window for templates.